# Return all nodes from hash table

Tags: javascript

I try to return all nodes from a hash function.

So I have it like this:

```
class HasTable {
  constructor(size) {
    this.buckets = Array(size);
    this.numBuckets = this.buckets.length;
  }

  hash(key) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
      sum += key.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    let bucket = sum % this.numBuckets;
    return bucket;
  }

  insert(key, value) {
    let index = this.hash(key);
    console.log("INDEX", index);
    if (!this.buckets[index]) this.buckets[index] = new HashNode(key, value);
    else if (this.buckets[index].key === key) {
      this.buckets[index].value = value;
    } else {
      let currentNode = this.buckets[index];
      while (currentNode.next) {
        if (currentNode.next.key === key) {
          currentNode.next.value = value;
          return;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
      }
      currentNode.next = new HashNode(key, value);
    }
  }

  get(key) {
    let index = this.hash(key);
    if (!this.buckets[index]) return null;
    else {
      let currentNode = this.buckets[index];
      while (currentNode) {
        if (this.buckets[index].key === key) return currentNode.value;
        currentNode.next;
      }
      return null;
    }
  }

  returnAll() {
    let allNodes = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.numBuckets; i++) {
      let currentNode = this.buckets[i];
      while (currentNode) {
        allNodes.push({key: currentNode.key, value: currentNode.value});
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
      }

    }
    return allNodes;
    
  };
}

class HashNode {
  constructor(key, value, next) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next || null;
  }
}

let has = new HasTable(30);

has.insert("a", "gmail.com");
has.insert("b", "hotmail.com");
has.insert("b", "hotmailHOTMAIL.com");
has.insert("c", "gstar.com");
has.insert("d", "oke.com");
has.insert("e", "nice.com");
has.insert("e", "nice99.com");
has.insert("e", "nice101.com");

console.log(has.returnAll());
```

But the output is this:

```
0: {key: 'a', value: 'gmail.com'}
1: {key: 'b', value: 'hotmailHOTMAIL.com'}
2: {key: 'c', value: 'gstar.com'}
3: {key: 'd', value: 'oke.com'}
4: {key: 'e', value: 'nice101.com'}
```

Which is of course not correct. Because I have three keys with e

? My desired result is very clear.

I insert eight nodes. But if I call the returnAll method it returns only  nodes.

Comment: What's the desired result? `5: {key: 'e', value: ...}` ? You should put your desired result in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my understanding of the hash table goes, your implementation is behaving correctly. Chained entries are added to the bucket only if entries **with different keys** are mapped to the same hash. In your case you have entries **with the same key** inserted over and over, which causes the already existing entry being overwritten.
This is done by this piece of your code:

```
...
else if (this.buckets[index].key === key) {
  this.buckets[index].value = value;
}
...
```

Chained entries would be added for e.g.

```
has.insert("e", "nice.com");
has.insert("eZ", "nice99.com");
```